# scatterhist with filled dots

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I can produce a figure like this in Matlab

```
scatterhist(log(rand(1,100)),log(rand(1,100)),'Marker','o','Direction','out');
```

however I trying to get filled dots instead of open circles as markers seems surprisingly hard to do: Parameters used in the function `scatter` do not seem applicable in `scatterhist`. A quick Google didn't help, other stackoverflow show similar diagrams.

How to get filled point markers (optimally half-transparent)?!

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is add `'markerfacecolor','b'` to the options, but by some reason, Matlab removed this option of the `scatterhist`.

**You can do it by hand**, changing the graph properties after you plotted. `markerfacecolor` options appears when you select the axis with the scatter and using the options >Edit >Figure properties.

**Or you can use the following commands**:

```
scatterhist(log(rand(1,100)),log(rand(1,100)),'Marker','o','Direction','out');
x=get(gca,'children')
x = 
  Line with properties:
              Color: [0 0.447 0.741]
          LineStyle: 'none'
          LineWidth: 0.5
             Marker: 'o'
         MarkerSize: 6
    MarkerFaceColor: 'none'
              XData: [1x100 double]
              YData: [1x100 double]
              ZData: [1x0 double]

  Show all properties

 set(x,'markerfacecolor','k')
```

I set the color as black, you can set in whatever color you want.

The transparency in a scatter plot is set by `'markerfacealpha',0.2` and `'markeredgealpha',0.2` (0.2 is the ratio in this case). However it does not work for the scatterhist (at least until Matlab 2017a). If you need the transparency, better to use the scatter and histograms using subplot. It is more time consuming but shall do the job.

Comment: You can instead do `set(x,'Marker','.')` for actual dot markers (rather than filled circles).

Comment: @CrisLuengo, True it does the job as well for the `scatterhist`, however when using the `scatter` plot, it does not allow to change the size.(At least using 2017a)